# Python Django OperationalError no such column model.id

Tags: python, sql, django

When trying to access my model via the Admin webpage using Django, I get an Operational Error stating "no such column: model_name.id"

I did my migrations and all but I am still getting the same error.

I assume I am getting this error because I had to change the name of my model. Since, I had to delete my database and migrations and had to re migrate all of my changes.

I originally got the error of not having a table built so I used some SQL to build the table and now I am stuck with a missing column under the name "id". Thanks in advance.

My models:

```
class PersonalUse(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    verification = models.IntegerField()
    messages = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    message_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Post your models.py

Comment: Don't build your own tables.  Django's migration system will handle this for you, including the implicit id field.